# How to send data stored in biguqery to downstream oracle databse?

Tags: oracle, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, sqoop

I have a requirement where, I would like to send data from my BigQuery to oracle db?
do we have any similar functionality like hadoop sqoop export in GCP, to send data from BigQuery tables to oracle db?

Frequency is daily

I need some solution or ideas around what would be best way to implement this.

Comment: What update frequency do you expect? Daily? Hourly?

Comment: Hi , It would be  daily frequencey

Comment: Why don't you use export statement in that case? And partition your BigQuery table at daily granularity. Like that, you send only the delta, and you optimize cost by query only specific partition in BigQuery. https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/other-statements#export_data_statement

Comment: Thanks for the reference link. will check that out.